How to use ScriptedActionHandler or ScriptedRulesEngine in NiFi - Examples are needed
In Apache Nifi there are controller services for scripted rules processing: ScriptedActionHandler, ScriptedRulesEngine.
The description is very promising, but documentation does not provide any clue how to actually use these services inside the data flows. Google also does not offer details in that issue.
In particular it is not clear how to fire the rule, how to supply the facts and what does actually the fact mean in the context of the dataflow ?
Any help or actual examples are highly appreciated.
